# Centos 7 , API calls makes IP banned

Tags: security, centos, fail2ban

I have this problem with multiple cents 7 servers. When users make tomany calls (via API, e-mail or ssh) the server automatically bans the IP for X time. I already setup CSF + Fail2Ban, changed 'max reties' to a higher grade but still people are getting banned.

1) How can I change the max retries to a higher limit ?
2) Can I get an e-mail notification when an IP is getting banned ?

Hope someone can help me out..

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be using csf and fail2ban together, since part of the installation of csf is to disable fail2ban and use it's own lfd daemon.

csf has the ability to report any blocks via email, using templates or by default, sending to the "root" account of the linux server.

You can typically setup the root account to go to a real address under /etc/aliases (and then running newaliases when /etc/aliases is changed).

HTH.